# Castle Windsor Resolving Mutiple Generic Implementations of 1 Inteface

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Suppose I have the following:

```
public interface IFileHandler<TLocation,TRow> { ... }

//loads file in some location using record format defined in RowTypeA
//e.g. RowTypeA records exist in files that match string 'file_a.csv' 
public class FileHandlerA<TLocation> : IFileHandler<TLocation, RowTypeA>{ ... }

//loads file in some location using record format defined in RowTypeB
//e.g. RowTypeB records exist in files that match string 'file_b.csv' 
public class FileHandlerB<TLocation> : IFileHandler<TLocation, RowTypeB>{ ... }

public class MyCode {
    ...
    public void MyMethod()
    {
       //here is how I would like to resolve file handlers
        var fh1 = container.Resolve<IFileHandler<Location1, RowTypeA>>(); //resolves to FileHandlerA<Location1>
        var fh2 = container.Resolve<IFileHandler<Location2, RowTypeA>>(); //resolves to FileHandlerA<Location2>
        var fh3 = container.Resolve<IFileHandler<Location1, RowTypeB>>(); //resolves to FileHandlerB<Location1>
    }
    ... 
 }
```

**How do I do the registration in Castle Windsor for this? Or is there a better design for this problem?**

P.S.
I tried:

```
 Classes
     .FromAssembly(thisAssembly)
     .BasedOn(typeof(IFileHandler<,>)
     .WithServiceAllInterfaces();
```

Also thought about this:

```
Component
  .For<IFileHandler<,>()
  .ImplementedBy<???>
```

Comment: Personally, unless you had more than a few `TRow`, I would create `IFileHandlerRowTypeA<TLocation>` and `IFileHandlerRowTypeB<TLocation>` and use those for registration and resolving.

Comment: I have about 10 TRow types

Comment: what is wrong with the registration code you are using?

Comment: I can’t close TLocation generic. The resolutions don’t work. I get an error that the generic implementation constraints aren’t met.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work but haven't tested it:

```
 var locationTypes = typeof(ILocation).Assembly.GetTypes()
      .Where(t => !t.IsInterface && !t.IsGenericType).ToArray();

 var fileHandlerTypes = typeof(IFileHandler<,>).Assembly.GetTypes()
       .Where(t => !t.IsInterface && !t.IsGenericType && t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IFileHandler<,>))).ToArray();

 foreach (var fh in fileHandlerTypes)
       foreach(var locType in locationTypes)
           {
               var rowType = fh.BaseType.GenericTypeArguments[1];
               var requestedType = typeof(IFileHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(locType).MakeGenericType(rowType);
               container.Register(Component.For(requestedType, fh));
            }
```